# How can I use fog to edit a file on s3?

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, fog

I have a bunch of files on s3. I have fog set up with a .fog config file so I can fire up `fog` and get a prompt. Now how do I access and edit a file on s3, if I know its path?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is probably to use IRB or PRY to get a local copy of the file, or write a simple script to download, edit and then re-upload it. Assume you have a file named data.txt.

You can use the following script to initialize a connection to S3.

```
require 'fog'

connection = Fog::Storage.new({
  :provider                 => 'AWS',
  :aws_secret_access_key    => YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  :aws_access_key_id        => YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID
})

directory = connection.directories.get("all-my-data")
```

Then use the directory object to get a copy of your file on your local file-system.

```
local_file = File.open("/path/to/my/data.txt", "w")
file = directory.files.get('data.txt')
local_file.write(file.body)
local_file.close
```

Edit the file using your favorite editor and then upload it to S3 again.

```
file = directory.files.get('data.txt')
file.body = File.open("/path/to/my/data.txt")
file.save
```

Comment: I imagine there's a way to change a file's properties without re-uploading it, no? At any rate -- what you provided gets me the fog environment I need for experimenting (which isn't very easy to find in their docs). thanks!

Comment: I believe you can set header information without re-uploading a file. You can find more information in the [documentation](http://fog.io/1.1.1/storage/) or by browsing the [source code](http://github.com/fog/fog).