# If I edit an image in a rake task with RMagick, how do I manually save it back to S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image-processing, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I have an app where people can upload pics, they're saved on S3 using the Carrierwave & Fog combo.

I'm rewriting the app, so in a rake task I need to loop through all images, resize/crop them (with RMagick), and save them back to S3 where they originally lived. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, is there a succinct way to do this? I don't want to have to get another S3 gem if I can do this with Fog which I already have available to me.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it, thanks!

**EDIT**

Using these instructions [How can I use fog to edit a file on s3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209546/how-can-i-use-fog-to-edit-a-file-on-s3) I managed to get a handle on the file from S3... sort of. It's of type `Fog::Storage::AWS::File`, but how do I get a handle on the actual image so I can edit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was actually so simple, I didn't realize CarrierWave could recreate and re-save all my images with the `user.avatar.recreate_versions!` method!